# Docker `error from sender` for read only root file

Tags: docker, dockerignore

One of the folders in my project is read only:

```
ls -la client/cypress
drwxr-xr-x  10 user    staff   320 Nov  2 18:06 .
drwx------   2 root    staff    64 Nov  2 17:58 resource  <--- this one
```

I've ignored it in the `.dockerignore` at the base directory (context)

```
client/cypress/resource
```

simple docker def:

```
WORKDIR /src
COPY client/ client
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

`$ docker build .` fails with:
`error from sender: open client/cypress/resource: permission denied`

Running as sudo works, but why won't docker just ignore the file? If i ignore the directory that contains the folder it works fine. (I know i can chmod the file, but it's generated programmatically by other tooling)

Answer (score 0):

The **resource** folder has ownership as `root:staff` and permissions as `700`. That means only the **root** user is able to read/write/execute that folder. The group **staff** has no permissions over that folder.

Running with sudo will work since sudo executes the command using the root user.

Regarding the **.dockerignore** file: it depends on the permissions the .**dockerignore** file has. If the ownership is `root:staff` and that permissions are as `640` or even more restrictive, then if you execute the docker build . as a regular user, that user is not able to read the .**dockerignore** file.

That being said, not reading the .dockerignore file translates into ignoring that file and its' content.

Comment: The dockerfile is able to be read, it's permissions are OK

Comment: As you say, since there's no additional info provided, I really don't know what's going on there so I can't actually provide a better answer